# Why is this a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

The operations (+) and (*) are (over a set F of functions from a set S to the positive reals, and real scalars):

$$[f_1+f_{2}](x):= f_1(x)f_2(x)$$

$$a*f(x):=f(x)^a$$

$(F, R+, +, *)$ is apparently a vector space, but proving it, I can't figure out the distributive law, that $(a+b)*f(x) = a*f(x)+b*f(x)$.

I have $(a+b)*f(x)=ab*f(x)=f(x)^{ab}$

but, $a*f(x)+b*f(x)=f(x)^{a}+f(x)^{b}=f(x)^{a+b}$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Edited for horrible formatting

Answer (score 3):

"Addition is multiplication" holds only for *vectors*, not for *scalars*. Particularly, $(a + b) * f(x) = f(x)^{a + b}$.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, brushing up on my definitions...

Comment: How do we know by the way to allow the operation + for the real scalars? Is it so that a vector space can only have two operations on vectors and scalars have all operations allowed "in their field"?

Comment: Specifying "real scalars" implicitly means the _field_ of real numbers, i.e., ordinary addition and multiplication. :) Generally, in order to define a vector space you must specify a field $(K, +, \cdot)$ of scalars (including the field operations), a set $V$ of vectors, and vector space operations $\oplus:V \times V \to V$ of (vector) addition and $\odot:K \times V \to V$ of scalar multiplication. Usually we're careless about using distinct symbols for the two types of addition, but in your question the distinction matters.

Comment: That was my suspicion, it was confusing seeing + and + being different operations =) thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

$$(a+b) * f = f^{a+b} = f^a f^b = (a * f)(b*f)$$

So if we write $+$ for multiplication of functions, we have:

$$(a+b) * f = a*f + b*f$$